# Count files matching a pattern with GREP

Tags: windows, grep

I am on a windows server, and have installed GREP for win.  I need to count the number of file names that match (or do not match) a specific pattern.  I don't really need all the filenames listed out, I just need a total count of how many matched.  The tree structure that I will be searching is fairly large, so I'd like to conserve as much processing as possible.

I'm not very familiar with grep, but it looks like i can use the -l option to search for file names matching a given pattern.  So, for example, I could use

```
$grep -l -r this *.doc*
```

to search for all MS word files in the current folder and all child folders.  This would then return to me a listing of all those files.  i don't want the listing, i just want a count of how many it found.  Is this possible with GREP...or another tool?

thanks!

Comment: 'grep' is a generic name; it would help if you said exactly which version of this tool you have.

Comment: Absolutely:  Grep 2.5.4 for windows

Comment: I just found something about the -c option: "You can pass the -c option to grep command to suppress normal output and display a count of matching lines for each input file."  Would this option also work for searching file names?

Comment: No.  I'd go with BeniBela's answer.

Answer (score 7):

On linux you would use

```
grep -l -r this .doc | wc -l
```

to get the number of printed lines

Although -r .doc does not search all word files, you would use --include "*doc" .

And if you do not have wc, you can use grep again, to count the number of matches:

```
grep -l -r --include "*doc" this . | grep -c .
```

Comment: thank you.  but this solution (as i understand it) will write all the file names (that match that pattern) to a file.  I'd like to avoid writing all the matches to a file and just get the count.

Comment: No it will print them to stdout (i.e. keep it in memory) and then just print the count